# Twitter Search Results - API / Atom Feed

Tags: php, jquery, twitter, atom-feed

So I've got somewhat of a cool task and I'm just thinking it over. I'm more a designer so I thought I'd tap into the bright minds on here.

I am creating a basic page that displays the results from a twitter search results page. Put simply, I am displaying an atom feed with HTML. I'd like to do it with PHP, unless someone has something better in .net or ruby.

The following things are needed:

1. It must show a count of the number
   of results returned (max about
   1500).
2. It must show the 'tweets' or Atom
   feed results. The twitter API limits
   this to 100 per call, but allows
   pagination. (so we can show 100 per
   page).
3. It must update at least every 15 mins, if not instantly.

My idea so far:

1. use twitter-search.php and run it 15 times calling pages 1-15. Somehow cache these pages so it only uses an API call once every 15 mins (how would I do this?)

http://woork.blogspot.com/2009/06/simple-php-twitter-search-ready-to-use.html

2. Then once everything is loaded, use Jquery .size to count the number is 'tweet' divs

Any help/ Ideas is appreciated!

Comment: I've got a working model displaying 1000 tweets per page as per my method above.

Now I am just working on a caching solution so I will not go over twitter's 150 api calls per hour.

Comment: Maybe you can post exactly where you are stuck. People won't do everything for you.

Comment: Seems like you're figuring it out on your own. We'd be more than happy to help if you post where you're stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up using a few Twitter PHP scripts and melded them together to get 1000 results on 1 page. 10 x 100 each

Answer (score 1):

I am wondering how to get a twitter search RSS feed that shows, say, 500 results instead of just the first 15? That's not fun at all.